# Filter Postgres table based on tuples of values

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Imagine a table in Postgres:

```
Firstname     Surname      Age
------------------------------
Joe           Bloggs       5
Sam           Bloggs       7
Ellie         Jones        4
Mike          Smith        10
```

I would like to range-filter this, based on an array of pairs of values (tuples):

```
{Surname=Bloggs  &&   Age>=6 },
{Surname=Smith   &&   Age>=10}
```

To return:

```
Firstname     Surname      Age
------------------------------
Sam           Bloggs       7
Mike          Smith        10
```

I realise I can do this by hand-rolling a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE (t.Surname = 'Bloggs' AND t.Age >= 6 )
OR    (t.Surname = 'Smith'  AND t.Age >= 10)
```

However, I need to call this from C#, and I'm interested in solutions which avoid having to generate a plain-text SQL statement for every query.

Is it possible to do this with a 'generic' SQL statement, passing in some kind of array of tuples / composite types as a filter parameter?

In other RDBMS I could, for example, populate a temporary table with the pairs of values, and join on that table; or use a table-valued-parameter (in SQL Server). Is there an equivalent in Postgres + NpgSql?

PS: I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981553/388502) that using temporary tables for this may not be best practice in Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution we found was to pass in array of custom types, which you can then `unnest` into tabular form in the query, and join on to.

```
CREATE TYPE predicate_type AS (
    Surname text,
    Age int);

SELECT * FROM MyTable t
JOIN unnest('{"(Bloggs, 6)","(Smith, 10)"}'::predicate_type[]) p(Surname, Age)
ON t.Surname = p.Surname AND t.Age >= p.Age
```

I've defined the array argument literally here, but you can pass them in as parameters to your query.

For example, you can map an equivalent C# type to the Postgres type in Npgsql, then just pass a C# array of those types into your command as a parameter:
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html#mapping-your-clr-types

Answer (score 2):

I think a flexible way to pass something similar as a table-valued-parameter is to use JSON to pass an array of tuples that are used for the condition:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
  join json_array_elements('[{"surname": "Bloggs", "age": 6},
                             {"surname": "Smith", "age": 10}]') x 
    on (x ->> 'surname') = t.surname and t.age >= (x ->> 'age')::int;
```

From within your application you could pass the JSON as a string. Not sure how you pass parameters in NpPgSQL, in the following example the `?` is a parameter placeholder:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
  join json_array_elements(cast(? as json)) x 
    on (x ->> 'surname') = t.surname 
   and t.age >= (x ->> 'age')::int;
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have the exact same scenario in a C# app and do what your described in your temp table solution, only I use a normal physical table.  I overcome collisions by adding a userid field to the table, so it looks something like this:

```
create table user_data.user_list (
  user_id varchar(20) not null,
  item_1 text,
  item_2 numeric
)
```

Then the actual C# implementation (oversimplified below to demonstrate) is:

Clear out any previous entries:

```
string user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("delete from user_data.user_list " +
    "where user_id = :USER",
    conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("USER", user);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Insert the new records using `copy`:

```
using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport(
    "copy user_data.user_list from STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
{
    foreach (var tuple in userData)
    {
        writer.StartRow();
        writer.Write(user);
        writer.Write(tuple.Item1);
        writer.Write(tuple.Item2, NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
    }
}
```

And your final query ends up looking something like this:

```
select t.*
from
  table1 t
  join user_data.user_list ul on
    t.surname = ul.item_1 and
    t.age >= ul.item_2 and
    ul.user_id = :USER_ID
```

It has the additional advantage over GTTs in that it's easy to debug since the last uploaded values persist in the database for all users.